# In .net, is there an opposite function to Server.HTMLEncode()?

Tags: asp.net

.Net's Server.HTMLEncode() is the very helpful function that takes an HTML string and replaces special characters with their entity equivalents - "<" becomes &lt ; and so forth.

Is there a (built-in) function that does the reverse?  There doesn't seem to be, and I am incredulous.  While I could certainly write my own (and have in the past) Server.HTMLEncode has all kinds of cool handling for different string encodings and high-level unicode characters that I would really not have crash my hand-rolled decoder in a year's time.

What do other people do when they need the plain HTML back?

Update:
To answer the first batch of questions, I present the MSDN article on the 
[Server object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525541.aspx), which has Encode but no Decode...  I'm as amazed as anyone.

Update2: as several alert readers have pointed out, the docs I was looking at were for classic ASP, not ASP.Net.  Thanks guys, that's an important MSDN safety tip.

Comment: The MSDN docs you linked are for (Classic) ASP - not ASP.NET.

Comment: AH-HA!  And that's the last time I ask THAT coworker for document links.  ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking at the wrong docs. Check this out:

> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility_methods.aspx
>   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.htmlencode.aspx
>   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.htmldecode.aspx

Comment: Oh SNAP!  There we go.  Thank you very, very much.  I KNEW that had to be in there somewhere.

Answer (score 10):

Server.HtmlDecode ....

Answer (score 4):

You didn't see a HtmlDecode in the same place you found the HtmlEncode?

Answer (score 0):

HttpServerUtility.HtmlDecode

Answer (score 0):

Ah, MSDN, I love you.

There IS a Server.HTMLDecode() method, the documentation for the server object just doesn't mention that it exists.

Thanks, everybody!